# pass value of drop down menu to another page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a custom shopping cart that when clicking on the "add to cart" link, the value of the 
quantity selected in the drop menu and the product id will pass to the addCart page. I am having no problem with the product id passing, but the quantity select drop down menu is dynamically populated by the amount available in stock. I am unable to grab the selected quantity and pass it to the next page. I specifically want to know how to grab the value selected from the drop down menu to the addCart page.

The shopping page:

```
echo "<table class='tableadmin2'> 
<tr>
<td class='td2'><b>Add&nbsp;to&nbsp;Cart: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Product Information: </b></td> 
<td class='td2'><b>Product Photo: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Select Amount: </b></td>
</tr>";

$display6="SELECT * 
    FROM in_product LIMIT $start, $pagerows; " ; 
$displayResult6 = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $display6)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));

while($row6 = mysqli_fetch_array($displayResult6, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
$i = 1;
$x = $row6['ip_stock'];
$y = " ";
for($i = 1; $i <= $x; $i++) {
$y .= "<option value=' . $i . '> $i </option>";
 }            
echo "<tr>
<input type='hidden' id='prod' value='" . $row6['ip_id'] . "' /></td>
<td class='td2'><a href='addcartInstate.php?ip_id=" . $row6['ip_id'] . "'>Add To Cart&nbsp</a></td>
<td class='td2'><strong> " . $row6['ip_name'] . " </strong><br> " . $row6['ip_desc'] . " <br> $" . $row6['ip_price'] . " </td>
<td class='td2'><img alt='first' src=" . $row6['ip_image'] . " width='300' height='250'></td>
 <td class='td2'><br>
     <b>Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br>
            <select id='orderIn_quantity' name='orderIn_quantity'>
                <option value='Select'> Select </option> 
                " . $y . "                                              
            </select>
 </td>
</tr>";
```

}
    echo "";

The addCart page:

```
<?php 
echo "<table class='table10'> 
<tr>  
<td class='td2'><b>Product Name: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Quantity: </b></td>
<td class='td2'><b>Price: </b></td>
 </tr>";

if (isset($_GET['ip_id'])) {     
    $ip_id = $_GET['ip_id']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['ip_id']))  {    
    $ip_id = $_POST['ip_id'];
} 
if (isset($_GET['orderIn_quantity'])) {     
    $orderIn_quantity = $_GET['orderIn_quantity']; 
} elseif (isset($_POST['orderIn_quantity']))  {    
    $orderIn_Quantity = $_POST['orderIn_quantity'];
} 

$q = "SELECT * 
    FROM in_product WHERE ip_id = '$ip_id'; " ; 
$result = @mysqli_query($dbhandle, $q)
            or die(mysqli_error($dbhandle));
$rows = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
$total = $rows['ip_price'] * $orderIn_quantity;

echo "<tr>     
<input type='hidden' name='ip_id' value='" . $rows['ip_id'] . "' />
<td class='td2'>" . $rows['ip_name'] . " &nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>" . $orderIn_quantity . " &nbsp</td>
<td class='td2'>$" . $total . ".00 &nbsp</td>
</tr>";
echo"</table>";
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is your methodology. Since you are trying to use a link with a URL parameter as your add to cart method, the quantity cannot be known without modifying the URL of the link before sending.

It looks like you might be a little bit confused about the difference between $_GET and $_POST, and when to use which one. $_GET is for when you pass variables via URL parameters, while $_POST is when you post data to a page via form.

In your current implementation, this line:

```
 <input type='hidden' id='prod' value='" . $row6['ip_id'] . "' /></td>
```

is useless because you're not submitting a form, so this hidden variable never gets sent anywhere (also, the </td> tag doesn't appear to be opened anywhere,and if you were going to use this in a form, it needs a name attribute).

Likewise, your <select> menu is useless for the same reason.

I would recommend you change your methodology to use a  instead of the  . So your code on the shopping page might look like this:

```
echo "<tr>
<form method='post' action='addcartInstate.php' name='addToCartForm' id='addToCart Form'>
<input type='hidden' name='ip_id' id='prod' value='" . $row6['ip_id'] . "' />
<td class='td2'><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add To Cart' /></td>
<td class='td2'><strong> " . $row6['ip_name'] . " </strong><br> " . $row6['ip_desc'] . " <br> $" . $row6['ip_price'] . " </td>
<td class='td2'><img alt='first' src=" . $row6['ip_image'] . " width='300' height='250'></td>
<td class='td2'><br>
<b>Quantity:&nbsp;&nbsp;</b><br>
        <select id='orderIn_quantity' name='orderIn_quantity'>
            <option value='Select'> Select </option> 
            " . $y . "                                              
        </select>
</td>
</form>
</tr>";
```

Then in addcartInstate.php file:

```
$ip_id = $_POST['ip_id'];
$orderIn_Quantity = $_POST['orderIn_quantity'];
```

You can of course style the submit button to make it look nicer than the default.

There are other ways to achieve this as well, which you will learn as you continue to experiment, including using a link to trigger the form submit rather than a button.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I understand you methodology and agree with the form requirement. I have added the form and the other suggestions you have made and I feel like I am getting closer. After adding that code. I am now getting this error.

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: ip_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\fireworks\addcartInstate.php on line 24

Notice: Undefined variable: ip_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\fireworks\addcartInstate.php on line 34
 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`fireworks`.`order_instate`, CONSTRAINT `order_instate_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`ip_id`) REFERENCES `in_product` (`ip_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Comment: It still does not seem to be grabbing the ip_id. Is there something I am not doing? I have added the following code to the addcart as you have suggested.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['ip_id'])) {
   $ip_id = $_POST['ip_id'];
   } 
    
  if(isset($_POST['orderIn_quantity'])) {
   $orderIn_quantity = $_POST['orderIn_quantity'];
   }

Comment: Can you update your original post with the way you currently have your code?